# LibGdx catapult trajectory

Tags: android, libgdx, projectile

I'm trying to create a projectile, which when fired will behave as if it was shoot from catapult. The problem is to calculate trajectory. I have starting position. Also target is the closest enemy.

I tried to implement this formula, which I found in [2d projectile trajectory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10387100/2d-projectile-trajectory)

```
xn = x0 + v * t * cos(theta)
yn = y0 + v * t * sin(theta)
```

And this is how I implemented it:

```
    float v = 70f;
    t += Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime();
    angle -= 0.1f;
    float xn = originX + v* t * MathUtils.cosDeg(angle);
    float yn = originY + v* t * MathUtils.sinDeg(angle);
    position.set(x,y);
```

I'm trying to make projectile move along the trajectory line something like on video below, target is determined by the catapult, it's the closest enemy:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mwU24AuQibw

EDIT

```
private float g = 9.8f;
private float v = 50;

public void update()
{
    t = Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime();

    float dx = originX - target.x;
    float dy = originY - target.y;

    double radi = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(v, 4) - g * (g * dx * dx + 2 * dy * v * v));
    double theta1 = Math.atan((v*v + radi) / (g * dx));
    double theta2 = Math.atan((v*v - radi) / (g * dx));

    float xn = originX + v * t * MathUtils.cos((float) theta1);
    float yn = originY + v * t * MathUtils.sin((float) theta2);

    position.add(xn,yn);
```

I did the above code, but it makes the projectile to disappear, because I used `add(xn,yn)`, but if I use `set(xn, yn)`, projectile doesn't move at all. I was changing v trying different numbers, it doesn't make any difference. Also theta1 and theta2 gives me a NaN value.

FINAL EDIT

I tried all ways which I could think of, of implementing these formulas and it didn't work for me. I decided to make something different instead. Thank you all for the answers. I'll keep this thread so that someone may use the formulas posted here.

Comment: What exactly is your problem? "I'm struggling" is not enough information. Also: do you use box2d?

Comment: I'm not using box2D. I'm using just libGDX. I need to move a projectile along the lines of trajectory. Difficult to explain, but basically projectile which is fired from catapult. That's how it should behave.

Comment: Therefore I need to calculate trajectory and make projectile move to the target along the lines of this trajectory if that makes sense.

Comment: Okay, and what exactly doesn't work?

Comment: From the formula I implemented, trajectory is hard coded, because I specified the angle. I need to calculate trajectory according to where catapult is targeting.

Comment: Depending on how far is the target that's how high angle will be. Therefore I think it's a good starting point to solve original problem. Any ideas how I can calculate that?

Comment: I found another example of what I'm trying to do, but it's done in cocos2D, which I'm not familiar with: http://www.raywenderlich.com/4756/how-to-make-a-catapult-shooting-game-with-cocos2d-and-box2d-part-1

Answer (score 3):

Your formula is not correctly used, because you assume the speed is constant (which is not true. Try shooting vertically, the speed should be 0 at some point), and the angle changes by 0.1 something no matter the amount of time elapsed.

`v` is the launch speed your projectile. `theta` is the launch angle. `(x0, y0)` is the launch position.

```
VX = v * cos(theta)
VY = v * sin(theta)
```

Gives you the correct launch vertical and horizontal speed.

Now, the alteration of the speed depends on 2 factors : air friction and gravity. Lets forget about friction for now.

`Vxn` is not subject to gravity. Therefore, it does not change.

`Vyn` is subject to gravity. It's value is given as function of time :

```
Vyn = VY + t * G
Vxn = VX
```

Where G is usually `~9.8m.s-2`.

Now, to measure your angle, you need to figure out where the projectile hits the ground. Thats `(Xtarget, Ytarget)`. `(Xt, Yt)` is the position of the projectile after time t has elapsed:

```
Xt = VX * t + x0
Yt = VY * t + 0.5 * G * t * t + y0
```

You want `Xt == Xtarget` and `Yt == Ytarget`

Given that you know v, the launch speed of the catapulte is known, this expression now only depends on theta (and t, but t can be expressed as a function of theta).

```
v * cos(theta) * t + x0 == Xtarget
v * sin(theta) * t + G * t * t + y0 == Ytarget
```

Solving this for theta should give you 2 solutions, one above and one below 45 degrees.

I have no idea how to do that for the moment.

## Edit

Found this http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trajectory_of_a_projectile#Angle_required_to_hit_coordinate_.28x.2Cy.29

The complete formula is

[image: Formula]

As you can see, there are 2 possible values (+-). I call dx the delta between Xtarget and x0, same goes for dy. This translates in :

```
radi = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(v, 4) - g * (g * dx * dx + 2 * dy * v * v));
theta1 = Math.atan((v*v + radi) / (g * dx))
theta2 = Math.atan((v*v - radi) / (g * dx))
```

Now, usually g = 9.8m.s-2, but it works only if dx is in m, v in m.s-1. You'll have to adjust the values of the constant if not.

Further reading, air resistance! http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trajectory_of_a_projectile#Trajectory_of_a_projectile_with_air_resistance

Comment: Thank you for your comprehensive answer. Is then Xt and Yt a current position of the projectile? Also is this Xt = VX * t + x0 a final statement to get position?

Comment: Xt = VX * t + x0
Yt = VY * t + 0.5 * G * t^2 + y0 If this is the final statement to calculate current position of the projectile, then it doesn't work. I'm getting numbers between 0.6 to 0.8 for X and between 0.002 and 0.003 for Y. It doesn't increment further. It just displays numbers between.

Comment: It's a great source, but I don't really understand maths behind it. If you could help me to put this into code, I would be grateful.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation, I'll do my best to implement what you wrote. I'll post results. With air resistance we are going to far. I wanted just to make my projectile move along the trajectory line and hit the target. And thank you for all your help.

Comment: Is dx and dy a distance between target and origin of the projectile?

Comment: Also should I put theta1 and theta2 to this formula to get position:               float xn = originX + v* t * MathUtils.cos(theta1);
float yn = originY + v* t * MathUtils.sin(theta2);

Comment: dx and dy : yes, that's the 2 components of the distance. theta1 and theta2 are the 2 solution of the equation. you need to choose only one. (it is a quadratic equation, and therefore has 2 solutions.)